# How to work on the result of two XML request simultaneously

Tags: javascript, xml

If I am getting some data from two different XML requests, how can I start some particular work at the instant both requests are done simultaneously.

Comment: Your not showing us any code,  but what I would suggest is you look into promises..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're solving is coordinating asynchronous tasks. You can accomplish this with callbacks.
When each request completes, have it run a callback function that will process all the output, but only if it's all present.

Here's the callback:

```
function allDone(){
    if ! (completedRequests < totalRequests) return;
    //If we get here, all calls are complete.
    //Add code here to work on your retrieved XML data.
}
```

Here's an example of getting XML, incrementing the counter, and calling `allDone()`.

```
function requestXML(url) {
    var dataToReturn;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "url",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            dataToReturn=xml;
            completedRequests += 1; //increment the count
            allDone(); //call the callback
        }
    });
    return dataToReturn;
}

var totalRequests=2; //There are going to be two requests, but we could easily extend this number.

var completedRequests=0; //here's the incrementing value

//Here are the two requests
var xml1=requestXML("xml_source1");
var xml2=requestXML("xml_source2");
```

`allDone()` gets called "totalRequests" times; all calls except the last one return from `allDone() immediately. The last time it gets called, it actually runs your code, once all the requests have completed.

I have refactored this answer to make Michael Kay's excellent point more obvious in this solution.

Comment: Thank you yes understood it but what if I have n requests.

Comment: If you have N requests then you just extend the idea in the obvious way, e.g. initialize a counter to N and decrement each time a task finishes.